# How to await a change in the value of a variable

Tags: javascript

When my JavaScript file is first loaded, an AJAX request is sent to a database. The trip usually takes about 30ms. On return, the data is stored in a variable. At this point, the variable is either initialized with the data or its initial value is changed. I then need to use the retrieved data.

So it seems I should be able to do something like this:

```
function async waitForData() {
    return new Promise(resolve) => {
        resolve(AJAXvariable);  // AJAXvariable gets correct value on AJAX return
    }
}
waitForData();
```

or:

```
const DBdata = async function(){
    return await AJAXvariable !== ""; 
}
```

In both cases, what's returned is the current value of AJAXvariable: undefined or "" or false. The await doesn't happen.

How can I write a promise that checks the value of a variable and doesn't resolve until that variable changes? Is this even possible?

Comment: Where's the actual _request_ being made? That's likely _already_ a promise, e.g. using fetch, resolving to the data.

Comment: First of all, "when the variable changes" makes no sense. Promises can only be fulfilled once. Do you mean "when the variable changes the first time". /// You need to call `resolve` when the variable is changed. You didn't provide enough info to help further. What changes the variable?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're even trying to do, but it's very likely you went about the wrong way of doing it before you got to this point.  Neither code segment makes much sense, they're just trying to wrap a Promise around a variable.  There's no asynchronous operation happening anywhere in the code shown.

Comment: Maybe I'm not clear on your problem but it sounds like you either need to make the call synchronous or continue processing/initialization in the async request's success method. If you're using a framework/library that has a model type then use that to store the value and register a change listener.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Reading your comments led me to the answer. Sorry if it wasn't clear, but what I needed, as ikegami suggested, was to call resolve when the   variable was changed the first time (which happened after an AJAX call). The point was just to wait till I received data from the database before continuing. I'm now using fetch (thanks, Jon) instead of my AJAX call to collect the data. After the fetch resolves, I use .then( ) to initialize the variable, and I'm good to go.